# Is this crazy vim register voodoo (incrementing alpha registers) possible within a macro?

Tags: vim

I have 4 lines.

```
foo ["bar"]
baz ["k"]
daskhfkjhadsfj ["askfjhfjdsh"]
dfjhafkjhfha ["skkksks"]
```

I'd like to do a macro that takes the word and yanks it into a register, but I want the register to increment. e.g.:

```
f"l"ayf"j0
f"l"byf"j0
f"l"cyf"j0
f"l"dyf"j0
```

Is there a way to get this command done in such a way that the registers autoincrement, so I can later paste them:

```
jjjj
f"ap   
j
f"bp
```

I'm aware of register numbering and yi" - i'd like to use this with alpha registers instead.  I'm also aware that a collision might occur with my chosen register:  You can assume that my macro will be recorded in z and I want to use, say, a-f for registers used.

Can you suggest a way to get this accomplished using a macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *a* macro?  Maybe.  With *two* macros, sure!

First some setup:

```
:set nrformats=alpha
:let @y="\"a"
```

And now some crazy Vim register voodoo:

`qzf"l@yyf"Go`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`"yp`<kbd>^A</kbd>`0"yy$dd`<kbd>^O</kbd>`j0q`

The strategy is to use one macro (`y`) to keep track of which register to use next, and modify it using the other macro.

- `f"l@yyf"` is from your original, only I've used `@y` in place of `"a`.  We're using the `y` macro to type `"a` instead of typing it directly.
- `Go`<kbd>Esc</kbd>`"yp` goes to the end of the file, adds a new line there, and pastes the contents of register `y`.
- <kbd>^A</kbd> increments the letter under the cursor.  If it was `a`, now it's `b`.  We set `nrformats=alpha` earlier so that this would work with letters.
- `0"yy$` yanks the updated text back into register `y`.
- `dd`<kbd>^O</kbd> cleans up our scratch line and jumps back to where we were before, and
- `j0` is the rest of your original.